# Difference between tikzpicture and pgfpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm not sure what's the difference between `tikzpicture` and `pgfpicture`.

I would like to make the following MWE within a `pgfpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,2) -- (3,4) -- (5,8);
  \draw (6,6) circle (3);
  \draw (8,8) .. controls (5,9) .. (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125001/is-there-an-advantage-in-using-the-pgf-basic-layer-over-tikz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tikz is a high level language which expands down into pgf which is low level and painful to write manually but much easier to convert to PDFs. Inside a `pgfpicture` you don't get `\draw` or anything like that but instead you get commands like `\pgfpoint` or `\pgfrect`. These can all be looked up in the tikz and pgf manual.

The first bit of your example would, inside a `pgfpicture`, look like:

```
\pgfline{\pgfpoint{1cm}{2cm}}{\pgfpoint{3cm}{4cm}}
\pgfline...
\pgfcircle[fill]{...}{3cm}
...
```

These are all explained fully and clearly in the tikz and pgf manual which is readily available online.

Comment: thanks for the explanation; but how I can draw a curved or bezier line in a pgfpicture?

Comment: @Micha Read part IX *The Basic Layer* of the manual, it describes all of this. (Skip straight to chapter 97.4 about *The Curve-To Path Operation* for bezier curves.)