# A programming language for TikZ/PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering if there existed any sort of "wrapper language" around the basic TikZ/PGF world. I'm in communication with a math professor who says he  "... used Python to generate large condensed blocks of TikZ code." Any information on what this might mean or documentation, examples?

Comment: There are two levels of tikz code.  The \path ... ; parser translates everything into things like \pgfpathmoveto and \pgfpathlineto.  If you use the [legend to name=...] feature of pgfplots, you can see what this looks like in the aux file.

Comment: Ti*k*Z is already the "wrapper" (or ["PR department"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125057/121799)) of pgf.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/94/

Comment: There is for example also [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz), which allows you to use svg as a kind of wrapper language for TikZ - not exactly what you intended with your question of course, but maybe still interesting.

Comment: I don't know if specifically TikZ/PGF is used, but LaTeX is used in the [manim engine](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) used for create impressive math animation on the YouTube channel [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw)

Comment: `matplotlib` has a `pgf` backend which spits out low level `pgf` code. Another possibility for `matplotlib` is `matplotlib2tikz`, which generates higher level `pgfplots` code.

Comment: Am I the professor?  Just send me an email and I can tell you more, if you'd like.  :)